# MariaDB. Create a trigger that deletes rows from a table older than 15 days

Tags: sql, mariadb

I want to create a database trigger that deletes automatically rows where the value of `happened_at` field is older than 15 days.

#### My table rows

```
id int(11)
site_id int(11)
user_id int(11)
data text
read bit(1)
deleted bit(1)
happened_at datetime
```

How can I do it?

I will try.

```
CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS `clean_older_than_15_days_logs`
ON SCHEDULE
  EVERY 15 DAY
  COMMENT 'Clean up log connections at 1 AM.'
  DO
    DELETE FROM log
    WHERE happened_at < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 DAY);
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: See: [MySQL Triggers](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers/)

Comment: Because "trigger is a stored program invoked automatically *in response to an event* such as insert, update, or delete that occurs in the associated table", you can't delete old rows automatically - this can be only happen when you modify data. You could likely create some kind of scheduled task, which deletes old rows nightly.

Comment: Your are not looking for a trigger but for a scheduled event.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will check.

Comment: Sherif, i added example to the topic. Is it ok?

Comment: You'll probably need [MariaDB CREATE EVENT](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/create-event/) to do it every day for rows that are older than 15 days.